# How to use filter method to filter array based on array field values in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, angular-filters

I have a add functionality for adding mulitlple groups by searching from a list of group array  . Each group has a roles(or multiple roles) assigned to it(see the listOfgroupsWithRoles array )

1. On first search i will return all the array of groups ( now suppose i selected a group which as "Admin" role and add it )
2. If a role added in the first search is an "Admin" role then on the next search to add a 2nd group i will have to filter out all the admin roles(since it is already added)  and only display the other roles like "Support" in the search functionality . For this purpose i am using the filters method to filter out the roles which are not "Admin"

for example:
my array is

```
func getGroupsWithRoles(){

listOfgroupsWithRoles= [{
    id: '1',
    group: 'Server group 1',
    role: ['Admin'],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    group: 'Server group 2',
    role: ['Admin', 'Support']
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Server group 3',
    role: ['Support']
  }
];

 return this.listOfgroupsWithRoles;
}
```

for the first search i display all the array elements and from the second search onwards i am using filter method
for filtering i am using two for loops since we have an array of roles to compare, but i am getting empty
array output.

```
this.filteredGroup =  this.listOfgroupsWithRoles().filter(x => {
                for (let j=0;j<=role.length;j++){    //role is from the the fisrt search ['Admin']
                    for (let i=0; i<=x.role.length; i++){ //x.role is from the  listOfgroupsWithRoles
                        x.role[i] !== role[j] //checking if both are not same
                       }  
                }       
            });
```

- while searching for 1 time ,
  i have to display all the groups and i added a group "Server group 1" which has admin role
  **Expected output below**

```
 [{
    id: '1',
    group: 'Server group 1',
    role: ['Admin'],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    group: 'Server group 2',
    role: ['Admin', 'Support']
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Server group 3',
    role: ['Support']
  }
];
```

while searching for 2nd time onward since the group with "Admin" was already added . I will have to exclude or filtered out all the group which doesn't have admin role.
**Expected output below**

```
 {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Server group 3',
    role: ['Support']
  }
```

--- but i am getting blank array output. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hey please edit and include the search functionality. There is something missing to understand exactly what happens in your app. Or even better a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: I see a basic problem here with the Array.filter method usage. Predicate callback is not returning true in any case. Basically you should return true for the objects that you want to filter in.
this.filteredGroup =  this.listOfgroupsWithRoles().filter(x => {
                // return true  for the objects that should be filtered in 
            });

Comment: @AmitHadary, please check now. added a snippet

Comment: @joe123 Hey I saw the photo you added. I did not mean to add a photo I mean the code implementation of your search is missing. I don't understand what event occurs when you select some group from the list

Answer (score 0):

If I can suggest this :

Base on **role = ["Admin"]** and **listOfgroupsWithRoles** is your table.

```
listOfgroupsWithRoles.filter(x => {
        let roleExists = false;
        for (let j=0;j<role.length;j++){    //role is from the the first search ['Admin']
            for (let i=0; i<x.role.length; i++){ //x.role is from the  listOfgroupsWithRoles
    
                if(x.role[i] === role[j]){ //checking if almost one value in Role table is present
                    roleExists = true
                }
            }
        } 
    
        if(!roleExists) {
            return true;   
        }
    });
```